# React-Redux - how do I dispatch actions from children components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, dispatch

I'm using [React with Redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux) and have this issue.

First I'm creating the `EditorContainer` component that introduces `store` and renders:

**EditorContainer.jsx:**

`<Provider store={store}>
  <Editor></Editor>
 </Provider>`

Dispatching actions within EditorContainer.jsx works just fine.

But I want to dispatch some actions in my Editor.jsx also so I do:

**Editor.jsx**

```
class Editor extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    store.dispatch(doSomething());
  }

  render() {
    return (
      // code
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  somethingPayload: somethingPayload
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Editor);
```

And of course I'm getting **Uncaught ReferenceError: store is not defined** in line number 3.

Shouldn't `connect` do the job here and include `store` & `dispatch` in **Editor** component in my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `this.props.dispatch` instead of `store.dispatch`, because the `dispatch` function is passed through the props.

Comment: Dude... I will marry you, just ask. Holy cow (can accept your answer in 9 minutes). So simple and I wasted half a day on this, d'oh! :(

Comment: Thanks, happy to help!